# How to attach schema to a Flink DataStream - on the fly?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep, flink-sql

I am dealing with a stream of database mutations, i.e., a change log stream. I want to able to transform the values using a SQL query. 
I am having difficulty putting together the following three concepts
`RowTypeInfo`, `Row`, and `DataStream`.

NOTE: I don't know the schema beforehand. I construct it on-fly using the data within the `Mutation` object (`Mutation` is a custom type)

More specifically I have code that looks like this.

```
val execEnv = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
val tableEnv: StreamTableEnvironment = TableEnvironment.getTableEnvironment(execEnv)

// Mutation is a custom type
val mutationStream: DataStream[Mutation] = ...
// toRows returns an object of type org.apache.flink.types.Row
val rowStream:DataStream[Row] = mutationStream.flatMap({mutation => toRows(mutation)})
tableEnv.registerDataStream("spinal_tap_table", rowStream)
tableEnv.sql("select col1 + 2")
```

NOTE: `Row` object is positional, and doesn't have a placeholder for column names.
I couldn't find a place to attach the schema to the `DataStream` object.

I want to pass some sort of a struct similar to `Row` that contains the complete information `{columnName: String, columnValue: Object, columnType: TypeInformation[_]}` for the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Flink SQL a table schema is mandatory when the `Table` defined. It is not possible to run queries on dynamically typed records.

Regarding the concepts of `RowTypeInfo`, `Row` and `DataStream`:

- `Row` is the actual record that holds the data
- `RowTypeInfo` is a schema description for `Row`s. It contains names and `TypeInformation` for each field of a `Row`.
- `DataStream` is a logical stream of records. A `DataStream[Row]` is a stream of rows. Note that this is not the actual stream but just an API concept to represent a stream in the API.

Comment: But the code snippet compiles - shouldn't it fail asking for schema? 
I guess my question is where in the line line do I attach the RowTypeInfo? 
Mutation is my custom type, and I can convert it to a row using the toRows function.
`val rowStream:DataStream[Row] = mutationStream.flatMap({mutation => toRows(mutation)})`

Comment: Oh I see. The compiler can only check the static types but not look into the fields of Row. That's a difference when using Row instead of Tuple which has the field types defined by generic types. You can attach a `RowTypeInfo` to any operater with the `returns()` method: `in.map(...).returns(Types.ROW(Types.STRING, Types.INT))`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! map and flatMap methods (operators?) both return a DataStream object that doesn't have a `returns` method. 

I noticed that `StreamTransformation` interface has the `returns` method. How do I extend and pass it instead of `flatmap`? Should I even be doing that?

Comment: Oh, sorry. `returns()` is only available for the Java DataStream API but you are using Scala. In Scala you can pass the `TypeInformation` as implicit value, i.e, `implicit val rowType: TypeInformation[Row] = Types.ROW(...)`

Comment: I see. The scala version of flatMap returns DataStream without `returns()` method. But the java one returns `SingleOutputStreamOperator`. That seems to make the compiler happy. 
`new DataStream[Row](mutationStream.javaStream.flatMap(mutationToRows).returns(rowTypeInfo))`

Comment: ^^Just saw your comment! Thanks Fabian